# ReloadData does not call CellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, reloaddata

I am absolutely sure that my `ReloadData` call does not call the `cellforrowatindexpath`.  I have an NSMutableArray that is full of 500 some values that I clear completely, then call `[self.tableView reloadData];` and nothing happens.  I put breakpoints and it calls number of rows but not cellforrow.  I set it up correctly I am a hundred percent sure but I am wondering if there is a different method to reload to a empty tableview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply does what is expected. If you clear your `NSMutableArray`, there are no entries in it. Number of rows will return 0, and hence there are no rows to call `cellForRow` for.

Comment: Hm, have you set your mutable array = nil? It's kind of weird that the rows don't get removed. You might try calling `deleteSections` or `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. See the manual at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9